# Multipe JQuery Searches in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that will ultimately have 10 different UL's with multiple DIV's in each LI which should have each DIV inside the LI's be searchable. Each searchbox should be searching it's own UL individually without affecting the other UL's in the page. The solution that I am currently using is to replicate the search code while incrementing the selectors numerically. This creates a lot of redundancy.

How can I limit the redundancy and have each search still only affect it's own UL?

The following is the incremented code (Only twice instead of all 10 for the sake of brevity):

**The HTML:**

```
<h1>Search One</h1>
<input type="text" id="search1" value="" placeholder="enter search text" /> 

<div id="results1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Banana</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cherry</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Banana</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cucumber</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Berry</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cheese</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>Search Two</h1>
<input type="text" id="search2" value="" placeholder="enter search text" />

<div id="results2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Banana</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cherry</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Banana</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cucumber</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="listing-three">Apple</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Berry</div>|
      <div class="listing-three">Cheese</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**The JQuery**

```
$("#search1").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#results1 li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (string.indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
      $(this).show("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).hide("slow");
    }
  });
});

$("#search2").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#results2 li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (string.indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
      $(this).show("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).hide("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

I have included a Fiddle for ease of explanation and clarity of functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/MercyMayaGames/1pbwc98j/

Comment: use classes selector as adeneo said or make a plugin which you can call on selector eg. plugin mySearch() you can use $(id1).mySearch(), $(id2).mySearch() etc ...https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the input box, give an attribute to indicate which list it is for

```
<input type="text" id="search1" value="" placeholder="enter search text" class="searcher" data-search-in="results1"/>
```

Notice last two attributes `class` and `data-search-in`

Now you can refactor the code as

```
$(".searcher").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var searchIn = $(this).attr("data-search-in");
  $("#" + searchIn + " li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (string.indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
      $(this).show("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).hide("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and looks like I'll be able to use it to reduce quite a few of my other functions in other projects. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
//$("#search2").keyup(function() {
$(".search").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(this).find("+ .results li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
if (string.indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
  $(this).show("slow");
} else {
  $(this).hide("slow");
}
  });
});
```

I have changed `#search2` with `.search`, that means you should also add a class `search` to all your search boxes. Similarly, you need to add `results` class to all result divs. You may use class names as per your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead

```
<input type="text" class="search" value="" placeholder="enter search text" /> 

<div class="results">

....
```

and target elements based on position in the DOM

```
$(".search").on('keyup', function() {
    var searchText = this.value.toLowerCase();

    $(this).next('.results').find('li').each(function() {

        var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        if (string.indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
            $(this).show("slow");
        } else {
            $(this).hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1pbwc98j/6/)

Comment: This is a beautiful solution as well. I wish there was a way to mark multiple answers. I'm going to have to work out which will be the most efficient in the long run.

Thank you for your time. Your response actually taught me quite a bit.